# Get last month data from first day until last day in Firebird

Tags: sql, firebird

I am trying to query Firebird to get data from last month, from day 1 until last day (30 or 31 depending on the month). When I use the code below it gives me shifted dates from current, for example day 11/14/2017 until 12/13/2017.

The code:

```
WHERE DATE >= DATEADD(MONTH,-1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(2)) AND DATE<= 'TODAY'
```

The desired output is 11/01/2017 - 11/30/2017

What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't use Firebird but I've used PostgreSQL fairly extensively and I think this should work:

```
WHERE 
    DATE BETWEEN dateadd(month, -1, CURRENT_DATE - EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE) + 1)
    AND CURRENT_DATE - EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE)
```

**Explanation**
     `CURRENT_DATE - EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE) + 1` should go back to the first of this month and `dateadd` with -1 month should take it to the previous month. Then if you're between `CURRENT_DATE - EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE)` or in other words 12/13/2017 - 13 days that should be the last day of November. Crossing my fingers. Good luck.

Comment: For Firebird, instead of `addmonth` use [`dateadd(-1, month, ...)`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-dateadd) (or `dateadd(-1 month to ...)`)

Comment: And I just noticed I had the wrong order of arguments for the comma-separated variant in my comment. Seems you got it right ;) One slight 'problem' is when comparing timestamps, it uses the current time (so taking 2017-11-01 21:06 - 2017-11-30 21:06, and not 00:00 - 23:59)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel it's ALL good. If you hadn't said anything, I would have never noticed. I've never used Firebird, gotta try it someday. Right now, I'm trying to scalp some questions to get my reputation points up. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Larry, checking the results, I saw that the code skips day 1 , that is, it starts from 11/02/2017. If I remove +1 from the code CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + 1 , it goes to 10/31/2017. Have any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: @JonathanLivingstonSeagull It might have to do that this solution searches between 2017-11-01 <current time> and 2017-11-30 <current time> (note that november has 30 days), so entries before/after current time are out of bounds. You will need to tweak Larry's solution a bit more to include those.

Comment: I tried to post a comment. @MarkRotteveel was correct, I shouldn't have used current_timestamp. Your date field is likely set to 2017-11-01 00:00:00 and the timestamp was greater. Sorry, I edited the answer. Take care!