# count the number of days of current month from day 1 until yesterday

Tags: sql, date, datetime, select, firebird

I am trying to calculate the number of days of the current of month from day 1 until yesterday without the need of changing the count manually. The original SQL as below:

```
select order_id 
from orders 
where date > dateadd(-23 to current_date) and date < 'today'
```

the desired code is something like

```
select order_id 
from orders 
where date > dateadd(datediff(day,firstdayofthemonth,current_date) to current_date) and date < 'today'
```

Appreciate any help

Comment: I notice that this is rather similar to your earlier question: [Get last month data from first day until last day in Firebird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47798555/get-last-month-data-from-first-day-until-last-day-in-firebird)

Comment: You ask about _"days of the current month from day 1 until yesterday"._  Just to clarify, what do you want to happen when the query is run on the 1st of a month?  Then "yesterday" will no longer be in the "current month".  Do you want zero results?  Do you want the previous month in its entirety?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In firebird you could do:

```
WHERE 
    date >= DATEADD(1 - EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE) DAY TO CURRENT_DATE) 
    AND date < CURRENT_DATE
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer provided by GMB, you can also use fact that Firebird allows addition of days to a date without needing to use `dateadd`:

```
date > current_date - extract(day from current_date) 
and date < current_date
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer provided by Mark, you can also use `BETWEEN` (starting with Firebird 2.0.4)

```
WHERE 
   date BETWEEN current_date - extract(day from current_date) + 1 
            AND current_date - 1
```

P.S. all those answers rely upon `DATE` data type (thus, `date` column and `CURRENT_DATE` variable) having no time part. Which is given for modern SQL dialect 3. But if Dialect 1 would get used it is not given.

- https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-commons-predicates.html
- https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-background.html#fblangref25-structure-dialects